# Strange SQL results when date condition in WHERE

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a table TABLE1 with a creationdate field (datetime) with the following example records

```
ID 1 12/12/2015 1:00:45    
ID 2 12/13/2015 00:00:00
```

if I execute the following query in studio manager it returns both records

the same query returns the correct records in a stored procedure

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CreationDate >= '12/12/2015' AND CreationDate <= '12/12/2015 23:59:59'
```

the query above is returning both records in studio manager. When it should only returning ID 1

I ran the same query by placing it in a stored proc and it returns the correct results.

Comment: Use the MySQL `BETWEEN` clause instead of the `<=` / `>=` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment and it might not fix your specific problem.

But, you should really use ISO standard date formats -- either YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.  In addition, there is no need to have seconds in the logic.  How about just doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CreationDate >= '2015-12-12' AND CreationDate < '2015-12-13'
```

Easier to type and it will even get times a few milliseconds before midnight.

Two common possible problems are (1) time zone issues (but this is ruled out with `datetime`) or (2) rounding issues.  Neither seems likely in this case.